# Having difficulty assigning patients and doctors together in Java

Tags: java

Ok so i have to make a program on hospital management system and i have to make a record of patients,doctors,appointment.. Now i already made patient and doctors record using objects and arraylist but i am having problems assigning a particular doctor to a patient according to the patient's illness.. This is what i basically did:-

```
 Appointment app1= new Appointment();
        Patient ap2= new Patient();
        Doctor ii2= new Doctor();
       for(i=0;i<appointments.size();i++){
           app1=appointments.get(i);
           ap2=patient.get(i);
           ii2=doctor.get(i);
           if(ap2.getIllness()==1){
            if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==1){
            System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
           System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
           System.out.println(app1.toString());
           }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==2){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==2){
                    System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
                   }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==3){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==3){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());

               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==4){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==4){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==5){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==5){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==6){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==6){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
       }
```

What is the mistake i am making here? I had a list of illness a patient could choose from thats why i used getillness()==1 and same goes for the doctor.. 
Just in case, i will show my entire program...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class patientdoctor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int id,num;
        int docid,docnum;
        Scanner src= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner ti= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner pick= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner newid= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner newname= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner newnum= new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner special= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,it,illness;
        int doci,docit,docspecialization;
        int pick1;
        String name,docname;
        String illname;
    ArrayList<Patient> patient= new ArrayList<Patient>();
    ArrayList<Doctor> doctor= new ArrayList<Doctor>();
        for(i=0;i<=2;i++){
            Patient xx = new Patient();
            System.out.println("Enter the ID of the patient");
            id=src.nextInt();
            xx.setId(id);
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the patient");
            name=ti.next();
            xx.setName(name);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of the patient");
            num=sc.nextInt();
            xx.setNum(num);
            System.out.println("Enter the illness of the patient");
            System.out.println("Type 1 if the patient has some sort of allergy");
            System.out.println("Type 2 if the patient has some sort of hearing problems");
            System.out.println("Type 3 if the patient has some teeth problems");
            System.out.println("Type 4 if the patient has some eye problems");
            System.out.println("Type 5 if the patient has some pregnancy problems");
            System.out.println("Type 6 if the patient has some heart problems");
            Scanner ill= new Scanner(System.in);
            illness=ill.nextInt();
            xx.setIllness(illness);
            if(illness==1){
                illname="Allergy";
                pick1=1;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            if(illness==2){
                illname="hearing problems";
                pick1=2;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            if(illness==3){
                illname="teeth problems";
                pick1=3;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            if(illness==4){
                illname="eye problem";
                pick1=4;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            if(illness==5){
                illname="pregnancy problems";
                pick1=5;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            if(illness==6){
                illname="heart problems";
                pick1=6;
                xx.setIllname(illname);
            }
            patient.add(xx);
        }

        Patient pp= new Patient();
        for(i=0;i<patient.size();i++){
        pp=patient.get(i);
        System.out.println(pp.toString());
    }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a patient");
        it=sc.nextInt();
        Patient tt= new Patient();
        for(i=0;i<patient.size();i++)
        {
        tt=patient.get(i);
        if(it==tt.getId()) 
        System.out.println(tt.toString());
        }
        int id1;
        System.out.println("Enter the id of the patient you want to update");
        Scanner id11= new Scanner(System.in);
        id1=id11.nextInt();
        int up,id2;
        String namess;
        int phones;
        Patient dd= new Patient();
        for(i=0;i<patient.size();i++){
            dd=patient.get(i);
            if(id1==dd.getId()){
                System.out.println("If you want to change the name, type 2");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the number, type 3");
                System.out.println("If you want to change the id, type 1");
                up=pick.nextInt();
                if(up==1){

                    System.out.println("Enter a new ID ");
                    Scanner idd= new Scanner(System.in);
                    id=idd.nextInt();
                    dd.setId(id);
                    patient.remove(dd);
                    patient.add(dd);
                    break;
            }
                else if(up==2){

                    System.out.println("Enter a new name");
                    Scanner namme=new Scanner(System.in);
                    namess=namme.next();
                    dd.setName(namess);
                    patient.remove(dd);
                    patient.add(dd);
                    break;
                }
                else if(up==3){

                    System.out.println("Enter a new phone");
                    Scanner newphone= new Scanner(System.in);
                    phones=newphone.nextInt();
                    dd.setNum(phones);
                    patient.remove(dd);
                    patient.add(dd);
                    break;
                }
        }

        } 
        System.out.println(dd);
        System.out.println("-----");
        for(i=0;i<patient.size();i++){
            pp=patient.get(i);
            System.out.println(pp.toString());
        }
        for(i=0;i<=3;i++){
            Doctor xx = new Doctor();
            System.out.println("Enter the ID of the Doctor");
            docid=src.nextInt();
            xx.setDocid(docid);
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the Doctor");
            docname=ti.next();
            xx.setDocname(docname);
            System.out.println("Enter the number of the Doctor");
            docnum=sc.nextInt();

               System.out.println("Enter the Doctor "+xx.getDocname()+" specialization");
               System.out.println("Type 1 for Allergist");
               System.out.println("Type 2 for Audiologist");
               System.out.println("Type 3 for Dentist");
               System.out.println("Type 4 for Ophthalmologist");
               System.out.println("Type 5 for Obstetrician");
               System.out.println("Type 6 for Cardiologist");
               Scanner specials= new Scanner(System.in);
               docspecialization=specials.nextInt();
            xx.setDocspecialization(docspecialization);
            xx.setDocnum(docnum);
            doctor.add(xx);
        }
        Doctor ppt= new Doctor();
        for(i=0;i<doctor.size();i++){
        ppt=doctor.get(i);
        System.out.println(ppt.toString());
    }
        System.out.println("Enter the id of a doctor");
        int dit=sc.nextInt();
        Doctor tht= new Doctor();
        for(i=0;i<doctor.size();i++)
        {
        tht=doctor.get(i);
        if(dit==tht.getDocid())
        System.out.println(tht.toString());
        }

        System.out.println("Enter the ID of the doctor you want to remove from the record");
        Doctor qq= new Doctor();
        int search;
        Scanner removedoc= new Scanner(System.in);
        search=removedoc.nextInt();
        for(i=0;i<doctor.size();i++)
        {
            qq=doctor.get(i);
            if(search==qq.getDocid()){
                doctor.remove(qq);
            }
        }
        Doctor kk= new Doctor();
        for(i=0;i<doctor.size();i++){
            kk=doctor.get(i);
            System.out.println(doctor.get(i));
        }
        ArrayList<Appointment> appointments= new ArrayList<Appointment>(); 
        int month,year;
        int day;
        Patient ap= new Patient();
        Doctor ii= new Doctor();
        for(i=0;i<patient.size();i++){
            Appointment app= new Appointment();
            ap=patient.get(i);
            ii=doctor.get(i);
            System.out.println("Enter the year "+ap.getId()+"  has an appointment");
            Scanner patapp= new Scanner(System.in);
            year=patapp.nextInt();
            app.setYear(year);
            System.out.println("Enter the day "+ap.getId()+" has an appointment");
            Scanner dayapp= new Scanner(System.in);
            day=dayapp.nextInt();
            app.setDay(day);
            System.out.println("Enter the month"+ap.getId()+" has an appointment");
            Scanner timeapp= new Scanner(System.in);
            month=timeapp.nextInt();
            app.setMonth(month);
            appointments.add(app);
        }
        Appointment app1= new Appointment();
        Patient ap2= new Patient();
        Doctor ii2= new Doctor();
       for(i=0;i<appointments.size();i++){
           app1=appointments.get(i);
           ap2=patient.get(i);
           ii2=doctor.get(i);
           if(ap2.getIllness()==1){
            if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==1){
            System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
           System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
           System.out.println(app1.toString());
           }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==2){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==2){
                    System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
                   }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==3){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==3){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());

               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==4){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==4){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==5){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==5){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
           if(ap2.getIllness()==6){
               if(ii2.getDocspecialization()==6){
                   System.out.println("the patient "+ap2.getId()+" is appointed to "+ii2.getDocname());
                   System.out.println("Appointment of patient"+ap2.getId());
                   System.out.println(app1.toString());
               }
           }
       }

                }
            }
```

Comment: While iterating through your appointments, you only check the doctor and the patient that have the same index as your appointment. I suppose you'll have to iterate through all doctors (per patient) in order to find a match. Also, did you hear of the [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)?

Comment: Can u please demonstrate it for me? :/